# Combining the partial Derivatives

Tags: partial-derivative

Suppose I have a column matrix $x = \begin{pmatrix}x1\\x2\\x3 \end{pmatrix}$ and another column matrix $y = \begin{pmatrix}y1\\y2\\y3 \end{pmatrix}$. I know all the partial derivatives of $y$ with respect to $x$. Lets say they are
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}y = \begin{pmatrix}y'_i1\\y'_i2\\y'_i3\end{pmatrix}$$ for $i \leq 3$.

Now my question is how can I get $\frac{d}{dx} (y)$, i.e., I want to differentiate $y$ with respect to $x$. How can I get that?

P.S. I am not a mathematics major so this may be a very lame question. But I want to know that. This is actually a subproblem that I need to solve for my original problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $$\mathbf{y}=\begin{bmatrix}
y_1 \\
y_2 \\
\vdots \\
y_m \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
\mathbf{x} =
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
\vdots \\
x_n \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then 
$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{y}}{\partial \mathbf{x}} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_2} & \cdots & \frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_n}\\
\frac{\partial y_2}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial y_2}{\partial x_2} & \cdots & \frac{\partial y_2}{\partial x_n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\frac{\partial y_m}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial y_m}{\partial x_2} & \cdots & \frac{\partial y_m}{\partial x_n}\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.